# How to capture List Dialog result - Android

Tags: android, dialog

I am new to Android. I am stuck, need help.

I have a List as my `Activity`. `OnItemLongClickListener` for any element of a List, I am displaying a Dialog with Custom List (Red, Green, Blue) & on the selection of any of the items (Red, Green, Blue) I need to change the back color of the selected item (on which the event raised the Dialog) of a List (main activity).

The dialog box pops, but I am stuck how to get the selected item (of Dialog). Below is my code.

```
 public class SimpleList extends ListActivity 
 {  
  String[] contactNames = {"Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5", "Name 6"};  

 ArrayAdapter<String> contactAdpater;  
 String itemSelected;  
 String choosenColor;  
 private final Context context = this;  

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
{  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   ArrayList<String> myContactList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(contactNames));  

  OnItemLongClickListener itemChangeColorListener = new OnItemLongClickListener() {  
  @Override  
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {  
     itemSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();  
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);  
final String[] colorNames = {"Red","Green","Blue"};  
builder.setTitle("Pick a Colour!")    
       .setItems(colorNames, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()   
              {  
            @Override  
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)   
                 {  
          choosenColor = colorNames[which];  
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), colorNames[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); <<-- its working fine here  

                   //I am not able to access parent here... I want to perform,  
                 **//parent[position].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); in case Red is selected from Dialog**  

      }  
         });  
             builder.show();      
        return false;  
    }  
 };  
 contactAdpater = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            myContactList);  
 setListAdapter(contactAdpater);  
 getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(itemChangeColorListener);   
  }  
 }
```

Comment: My main requirment is to change the color of my Main List Selected item to the selected Color from List Dialog. I am able to access itemSelected but not able to access parent.

Comment: & more over if I am able to access the parent (with your help), is it possible to change the back color or fore color of an List item?

Comment: I'd tried to reformat but what happened to the code... I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes got your problem

You have to use view's ***setBackgroundColor(int color);*** for changing the color if selected item of first ListView with the color selelcted from Dialog.

So In onClick you must use :

```
     choosenColor = colorNames[which];  

 if(choosenColor.equals("Red"))
 {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 }
 else if(choosenColor.equals("Blue"))
 {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
 }
 else if(choosenColor.equals("Green"))
 {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
 }
```

Comment: Welcome..Please accept the answer..So that it will be useful for other people here in SO

Comment: Kartik can you help in providing some links to learn android in-depth, with examples. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here are lot of stuffs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869338/where-to-start-to-learn-android and http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample

Comment: The link is having a lot of stuff! Thanks again!